# Initializing 2D arrays

Tags: java, arrays

this is my project,i have a question how to do the game begins with four pieces placed in a square in the middle of the grid:

```
import java.util.*;
public class prog{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int [][] table = new int[6][6];


        System.out.printf("   ");
        for(int i = 0; i<=5 ;i++ ) {
            System.out.printf("%2d",i);
        }
        System.out.println("\n  -------------");
        for (int h = 0; h <= 5; h++) {
            System.out.printf("%d |",h);
            for (int j = 0; j <= 5; j++) {
                System.out.printf("%2d",0);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please remove code that is not relevant and not used like `Scanner` and player.

Comment: "four pieces placed in a square in the middle of the grid". Is not very clear to me. I assume you want to assign values that are different than 0 to some parts of the printed grid. Try using `table` as data model. Initialize it with the values you want and then print it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood what you want to achieve try the following code. It is **not** the simplest answer to your question, but I believe it is better constructed:

```
//see Java Naming Conventions https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-naming-conventions/
class Prog{

    private static final int H = 6, W = 6, BLANK = 0, PIECE = 1;
    private static int [][] grid;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        grid = new int[H][W];
        intializeGrid();
        printGame();
        placePieceAt(2,2);
        placePieceAt(2,3);
        placePieceAt(3,2);
        placePieceAt(3,3);
        printGame();
    }

    private static void intializeGrid() {
        for (int row = 0; row < H; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < W; col++) {
                grid[row][col] = BLANK;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void printGame() {
        prtintHeader();
        printGrid();
    }
    private static void prtintHeader() {

        System.out.printf("\n   ");
        for(int i = 0; i < W ;i++ ) {
            System.out.printf("%2d",i);
        }
        System.out.println("\n  -------------");
    }

    private static void printGrid() {
        for (int h = 0; h < H; h++) {
            System.out.printf("%d |",h);
            for (int w = 0; w < W ; w++) {
                System.out.printf("%2d",grid[h][w]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private static void placePieceAt(int row, int col) {
        grid[row][col] = PIECE;
    }
}
```

Comment: great but can del the first table and do this ? because it can Easy to understand? thank you!!!
        placePieceAt(2,2) =2;
        placePieceAt(2,3) =1 ;
        placePieceAt(3,2)=1;
        placePieceAt(3,3)=2;

Comment: "great but can del the first table and do this ? " Not sure I understand.

Comment: your try the table have quadruple one but i want to have two one and one two how to do this ?

Comment: Try to follow what the dose does. That is the whole point. Change the code to do what you want. If you face difficulties, post a new question.